# Why can not import the module in sys.path?

Tags: python

```
root@rebuild:~# python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (default, Nov 27 2014, 13:54:17)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/root', '/root/Python-3.4.0/Lib/site-packages/}', '/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4', '/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']   
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls  /root/Python-3.4.0/Lib/site-packages/")                      
test.py  README
0
>>> import  test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'test'
```

It is strange that why can't import test module which is in the sys.path "/root/Python-3.4.0/Lib/site-packages/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import test.py
```

You imported your module `test` with the extension `.py`. So the import will try to find module named `py` in package `test`.

```
import test
```

Would be the correct syntax for importing a module.

For example :

```
>>> import string
>>> string
<module 'string' from 'C:\Python27\lib\string.pyc'>
```

Here `string` is module. But if you try to `import string.py` it treats `string` as `package` and trys to `import` `py` module.

```
>>> import string.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py
```

And you should also fix your `site-packages` path in `sys.path` which has '**}**' symbol at the end which is invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

For two reasons:

- Your `sys.path` is messed up (there's a trailing `}`).
- You're supposed to `import test`, not `import test.py`.

Please read the Python tutorial's section on modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html